# ASP.NET textboxes hold their text property after post back

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, view, postback

on the msdn we have this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx.
Generally the life of a web site looks like this:
Initialization->LoadViewState->LoadPostBackData->Load->RaisePostBackEvent->SaveViewState->Render

I have a placeholder on my aspx side it looks like this:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph1" runat="server">
  <asp:Button OnClick="ClickMe" ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

I'm creating two textboxes on the Page Load event the code looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <2; i++)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox(); 
    tb.ID = "tb" + i.ToString();
    tb.Text = "my test string";
    ph1.Controls.Add(tb);
}
```

And the click button event looks like this:

```
protected void ClickMe(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      var mycontrols = ph1.Controls;
}
```

When I put sommething in to those textboxes and click the button the page is postedback but my textboxes hold the inputed values despite  the fact that I'm changing their text property on the page Load event. Those controls are created dynamically on the Load event which is fired after the LoadViewState and LoadPostBackData so how does it work?? When do controls receive their postdata??

Comment: You're creating the objects dynamically - which means they are new objects in memory. Think of it this way, on every page load, you are re-creating the textboxes - so although tb1 is an object that has a value set to "foo" on postback, you are creating a new object called tb2 - it wont retain the viewstate.

Comment: @RPM1984 This has nothing to do with viewstate

Comment: But my problem is that those textboxes holds the text property which were inputed on the page. I see the textbox on the page and I input "my text blablabla" then I Click the button and my textbox still shows the "my text blablabla" so when the new textbox created again on the load event received this property?? This happens only to controls created dynamically....and textbox doesn't hold its value in the stateview but in the postbackdata, you can turn off the viewstate for this control and it's still holding it's value after postback

Comment: @matt-dot-net. Maybe i am misunderstanding the question then (by the looks of the OP's latest comment, looks like i am). What does this have to do with then?

Comment: How did you access the textbox value in ClickMe()?

Comment: var mycontrols = ph1.Controls;
In debug is have the list of controls from ph1 in mycontrol..
In the RaisePostBackEvent I already have my textboxes filled with previous inputed values...So it must be happening between Load when i try to change those property to "my test string" and the RaisePostBackEvent...

Comment: @shin what is your expected result? Seeing the text you type in or the text you hard coded in Page Load? I suggest moving the code from Page Load to Page Init event.

Comment: @shin, in fact, are you trying to work out why the dynamically created textbox receive the post back value after the page LoadPostBackData?

Comment: yes...why the load event doestn't override this value...in some way it does but then again after that the values from post are set to it again

Comment: @shin I suspect that the TextBox itself is calling LoadPostData() itself to load the data not the page. From a OO point of view it seems to be correct. May be try to create a new TextBox control inheriting from the default one and override the LoadPostData() to see if that's the case? See the link for reference.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.loadpostdata.aspx

Comment: @shin, I guess this post (and some links on it) has the answer you wanted.

http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/308591-loadpostdata-not-being-called-right-time-controls-dynamically-added-page-load

Comment: I think that's the answer that"Controls added during page
load will have LoadPostData called *after* their page loads and not
before" so I think we managed to solve my problem :) I just can't accept the answer coz we're just commenting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your premise of the order of events is slightly wrong.  See this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479328.aspx.  You'll find that the ProcessPostData actually occurs twice, once before PageLoad,and once after to handle dynamically created controls that weren't present the first time.

Also, it is a common misconception that this has something to do with ViewState.  It does not.  Try setting EnableViewState=false on your textboxes and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Yes I know about the ViewState and thanks the question is answered ;)